# object required error 424 when copying a sheet from closed workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I got the rest of my other sub working the way I want it to.  It just highlights cells of interest and hides rows that are irrelevant to me across a number of worksheets.  One of the last manual processes for me in this is copying a worksheet into the report every day to run the sub.  I finally got it working as a standalone sub:

```
Sub OrbitAdd()
Dim wbOrbit As Workbook
Dim wbTop As Workbook
Set wbTop = ActiveWorkbook
Set wbOrbit = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\*****\Orbit.xlsx")
wbOrbit.Sheets(1).Copy after:=wbTop.Sheets(7)
wbOrbit.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

When I went to incorporate this into the main sub is when it broke.  I tried a basic Call OrbitAdd() and it threw an error (I forget which error).  I think it was looking for some arguments to pass to the sub maybe?  When I tried to copy this in there directly it would run and add the worksheet and close the workbook before throwing the object required 424 error.  As far as I can tell it didn't do anything after closing the workbook.

Why is this working as an independent sub, and not no matter how I try to incorporate it into the main sub?  What am I missing or need to do to transition from this block of code back to the main sub to handle the error?  (the **** in the file path are to obscure irrelevant file path info)

edit: adding the next few lines from my main sub for further troubleshooting help.  The only thing before the first shared code block is turning off screen updating and dimensioning parameters for the rest of the sub.

```
'sets Orbit range to the size of the eNodeB site list
With Sheet8
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Orbit = .Range("A1").Resize(lastRow, 1)
End With

'Clearing conditional formatting from the workbook.
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
Next ws


'iterates each worksheet with the tables to apply the formatting.
For j = 1 To 3
    If j = 1 Then
        Set ws = Sheet2
    ElseIf j = 2 Then
        Set ws = Sheet3
```

Comment: I'll also note that the error message that pops up with the 424 leaves the debug button grayed out, so I don't have a good place to start looking for issues.

Comment: If you got the error *after* the workbook closed then that seems to point to some other code as the problem.  Since the code you posted looks and works fine, there's not much we can do with that.  If the Debug button is greyed out, try setting your VBA error handling to "Break in class module", and make sure your VB project isn't protected.

Comment: Ok. I'll give that a try.  I was wondering if there was something I might need to add as a transition between that and the rest of my main sub.  they both work just fine independently.  If I run this first and then run the main sub it does everything I want it to.  They just aren't integrating together.  I tried doing a wbTop.Activate after the close to try and make sure any sheet reference afterwards was referencing the correct workbook, but that didn't seem to help either.  None of my VB projects are protected.  I'm still very new to VB and don't know how to do any of that.

Comment: Without seeing the rest of your code it's difficult to guess what the problem might be.

Comment: @TimWilliams   I edited my initial post to add the next several lines of my main sub.

Comment: That looks fine to me provided all those sheet references are valid.

Comment: Those sheet references are all fine. They worked no problem before adding the block of code to copy that worksheet in.  Sheet8 is a direct reference to the worksheet that I added from the other workbook into this workbook.

Comment: You mean `WorkSheets(8)`  ?  `Sheet8` is not guaranteed if you copied the sheet from another workbook.  Code names and sheet indexes are not necessarily related.

Comment: Correct.  Because these report files have a standard format whenever I add that sheet it's always shows up in the VBEditor as Sheet8 as long as the workbook stays open.  If I were to save and close it, the location of the added sheet would impact those sheet reference names once I open it again. That's why I add the sheet to the end of the workbook.  I checked and tested that out several times to make sure that behavior was consistent.  Also, I've not gotten the hang on the nuance between calling worksheets vs sheets() vs just the direct Sheet#.

Comment: WorkSheets(8) is the safest approach here, if you know the sheet's index is 8.  Using the sheet's codename is not robust.

Comment: ok. I'll give that a try.  It'll be a bit before I can get back to testing this out yet.

Comment: @TimWilliams so that change on just that one sheet (instead of throughout the entire sub) seems to have solved the issue.  So that goes back to what was so different between the 2 that it caused the issue?  Does VBA look for all Sheet# references ahead of running any operations, in which case Sheet8 didn't exist at that point in time?  So using Sheet8 refers to the code name visible in the VBE panel, which is obviously more robust than Sheets("orbit") since someone could just go in and change the sheet name.  Then WorkSheets(8) refers to the worksheet in position 8 regardless of what that is?

Comment: I just ran into a new oddity with this.  I ran it on 1 workbook, and it ran great.  I then dragged the modules to another open workbook to try since I get a few of these reports daily.  It likewise ran and did all the highlights and formatting that I wanted, but I noticed on this second workbook, it didn't actually copy that new sheet over.  Why might that be?

Comment: If you're copying a worksheet to a known location in a workbook, then accessing the copied sheet by its sheet index (being careful with hidden sheets if you have any) is the safest way to reference the copied sheet.  There's no fixed relationship between worksheet code names and sheet positions: it only looks that way in a new workbook.  Dragging a sheet tab left or right in a workbook doesn't change its codename.

Comment: I can't tell why it might have failed when copied to a different workbook.  If it didn't even copy the sheet then there's a whole other problem.

Comment: It copied the sheet again to the first workbook I ran it on, instead of to the second.  so it copied it to the wrong workbook for some reason.
edit:  I think I may not have been careful enough with which workbook was last pulled up before running it, so it copied it to the activeworkbook instead of thisworkbook

Comment: Did you copy a sheet with a button and not map the button macro target to the new workbook?

Comment: Nah. I don't know how to make buttons or any of that yet.  This is just a straight VBA macro.  I think what happened is I dragged the module to the workbook in the VBE for both of the workbooks. I ran it on the one, checked it and saved it. Then I ran the other one without first bringing it up, so that it was active.  Thus the reference in my code in the initial report added the sheet to the first workbook, but then performed the rest of the actions on the second workbook.

Comment: Which brings up a question.  Do I need to drag the module to the workbook I want to run it on, or is there a way I can leave it in my personal.xlsb and run it on the workbook I open without having to go through the whole VBE?

Comment: You can always reference the `ActiveWorkbook` from any other VB project's code.

Comment: So if I did a Dim wb As Workbook and Set wb = ActiveWorkbook at the beginning, then I just need to add wb. in front of everywhere else where I have ws. in there already?  Part of my remaining question there is in the second block of example code in my initial post where I have Set ws = Sheet2 and the rest of those lines ... Do I need to add a wb. in front of the Sheet#?  do I have to change the Sheet# to something else to make it work right?